# Amazon aws AthenaClient or jdbc query: SdkClientException UnknownHostException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an implementation to get data from the Amazon AWS cloud:

```
String athenaUser = "xxxxx";
String athenaPwd = "xxxxx";
AwsCredentialsProvider creds = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create(athenaUser, athenaPwd));
AthenaClientBuilder builder = AthenaClient.builder().region(Region.EU_WEST_1).credentialsProvider(creds);
AthenaClient athenaClient = builder.build();
QueryExecutionContext queryExecutionContext = QueryExecutionContext.builder().database("xxxxx").build();
ResultConfiguration resultConfiguration = ResultConfiguration.builder().outputLocation("s3://aws-athena-query-results-xxxxx-eu-west-1").build();
StartQueryExecutionRequest startQueryExecutionRequest = StartQueryExecutionRequest.builder().queryString(query).queryExecutionContext(queryExecutionContext).resultConfiguration(resultConfiguration).build();
StartQueryExecutionResponse startQueryExecutionResponse = athenaClient.startQueryExecution(startQueryExecutionRequest);
....
```

```
...
<dependency>
<groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
<artifactId>auth</artifactId>
<version>2.17.182</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
<artifactId>athena</artifactId>
<version>2.17.182</version>
</dependency>
...
```

This works very well on my local payara deployment.

I have a second alternative test implementation:

```
...
Class.forName("com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver");  
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=eu-west-1;User=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;S3OutputLocation=s3://aws-athena-query-results-xxxxx-eu-west-1;");
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet queryResults = statement.executeQuery(query);
...
```

This works also.

But when the code is deployed on a other system I get the following errors (for the second implementation I get a similar error):

```
...
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Received an UnknownHostException when attempting to interact with a service. See cause for the exact endpoint that is failing to resolve. If this is happening on an endpoint that previously worked, there may be a network connectivity issue or your DNS cache could be storing endpoints for too long.
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:102)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.interceptor.HelpfulUnknownHostExceptionInterceptor.modifyException(HelpfulUnknownHostExceptionInterceptor.java:59)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.interceptor.ExecutionInterceptorChain.modifyException(ExecutionInterceptorChain.java:199)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.ExceptionReportingUtils.runModifyException(ExceptionReportingUtils.java:54)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.ExceptionReportingUtils.reportFailureToInterceptors(ExceptionReportingUtils.java:38)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:39)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:193)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:103)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:167)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:82)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:175)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:76)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:45)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:56)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.services.athena.DefaultAthenaClient.startQueryExecution(DefaultAthenaClient.java:2532)
...
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: athena.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:102)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException.create(SdkClientException.java:47)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.RetryableStageHelper.setLastException(RetryableStageHelper.java:204)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:83)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:56)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:36)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:48)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.execute(ApiCallMetricCollectionStage.java:31)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)
    ... 115 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: athena.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1281)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:112)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.internal.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$DelegatingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
...
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this problem?
It is a problem for a system administrator? If yes, please explain it because I am a complete newbee for admin thinks.
Thanks for your hints Ann

Comment: Is your other system in a sandbox? Is it only restricted to specific domains? This isn't related to your code but more so the machine. `athena.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` will probably need to be added to an allow-list of some sort.

Comment: Ermiya. Unfortunately, I cannot say, as the deployment is carried out in a customer environment to which I do not have access.

Comment: The customer will need to debug this then - they are blocking a legitimate domain name which is needed. That is your answer.